# Generating a barcode with a Zebra printer

Tags: printer, barcode

Please excuse my ignorance if this question is very elementary, but I am new to generating barcodes and Zebra printers.  Specifically Z4M, Z4M Plus, and a Z400.

In my previous post I was suggested to use the driver for the printer over the Generic Text drive in Windows so I could have multiple printers using the same driver.

[Windows XP Generic Text Driver and Printer Name Bug](https://superuser.com/questions/255912/windows-xp-generic-text-driver-and-printer-name-bug)

This solved my initial problem, but now I'm having issues getting the barcode to generate.  I know Zebra's have their own markup language and can self generate a barcode, but since I switched to the printers driver, the markup language quit creating a barcode.

Is there a way to call the generate function with the printers driver, or do I need to create a barcode locally in my VB Web application, before sending to a printer?

Comment: What model of device are you working with?  The linked question makes it unclear: Did you wind up sticking with the Generic Text driver, or switching to a Zebra driver?

Comment: I did switched to the Zebra driver.  I am using a Z4M, Z4M Plus, and a Z400.

Answer (score -1):

Service and support for all of those printers were discontinued by 2020. Replacement suggestion is ZT411. See https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/printers/industrial/zm400.html. I replaced my old Zebra printers with GK420t and ZD421.

According to the ZPL language http://labelary.com/zpl.html
a simple 1234 barcode can be sent using:

> ^XA
> ^FO 60, 120 ^BY 3 ^BC , 60, , , , A ^FD 1234ABC ^FS
> ^XZ